# Codeigniter - Model - Duplicate Entry Alert

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

made a simple subscription form submit email and city only email id i set unique but if email id is already in database it shows error i need to add alert here if data already in database alert to user but dont show the complete details like this.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1062
>
> Duplicate entry 'abc@abc' for key 2
>
> INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `city`) VALUES ('abdullah@gaya.com',
>   'jeddah')
>
> Filename:
>   /home/content/f/a/h/fahadghafoor/html/fahad/models/users_model.php
>
> Line Number: 12

Model file user_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Users_model extends CI_Model
    {


    function create_member()
    {
            $new_member_insert_data = array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),                           
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data);
            return $insert;


    }//create_member
}
```

Controller file user.php

```
<?php 

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('user_agent');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function create_user() {
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            if ($this->input->post("lang") == "en") {
                if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                    $this->load->view('m_english_signup');
                } else {
                    $this->load->view('d_english_signup');
                }
            } //if ($this->agent->is_mobile())
            else {
                if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                    $this->load->view('m_arabic_signup');
                } else {
                    $this->load->view('d_arabic_signup');
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->load->model('Users_model');
            if ($query = $this->Users_model->create_member()) {
                if ($this->input->post("lang") == "en") {
                    if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                        $this->load->view('m_english_thanks');
                    } else {
                        $this->load->view('d_english_thanks');
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                        $this->load->view('m_arabic_thanks');
                    } else {
                        $this->load->view('d_arabic_thanks');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: definitely sounds like a plan! Is there an actual question?

Comment: its an actual question because a normal form is ready now need to fix this duplicate error with alert warn for users.

Comment: Relequestual has the best answer you want to use a Callback. Note that with the callback you can create a custom error message which is what you want. Also break out the validation into its own method and if it passes - then go to a separate method. that way you won't have to repeat the same view calls over and over again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's very simple....Just change

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
```

with is_unique rule

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[TABLENAME.COLUMNNAME]');
```

TABLENAME - Your table name
COLUMNNAME - Your relevant column name which contains Email.Ex:-email

Answer (score 6):

In ./application/config/database.php set $db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;

And then try to catch the error number in your Users_model.

```
$insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data);
if (!$insert && $this->db->_error_number()==1062) {
   //some logics here, you may create some string here to alert user
} else {
   //other logics here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add custom form validation. The [CI documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) explains how to do that.

The callback will need to check to see if the email is already in the database and return true or false (Or rather, the opposite, as the callback must return true if the email is valid, and not in the database).

Hope that helps.